How to get postgres to clean up pg_wal at patroni standby instance?
We have a lot of postgresql clusters set up with patroni.
Most of the time and most of all clusters are behaving as expected.
But at one of the standby nodes WAL files are not removed and so pg_wal keeps growing until the underlying filesystem gets exhausted.
The setup is basically the same for this instance as for one of the other ones which are working as expected. (patroni 4.0.1 vs. patroni 4.0.2. / postgresql 14.13 on Oracle Linux 9.4)
I already found various documents and webpages describing the possible reasons for such behaviour.
https://www.cybertec-postgresql.com/en/why-does-my-pg_wal-keep-growing/
How to remove old WAL file in postgresql?
But none of the reasons there seems to match.
There's an inactive replication slot in the standby instance, but that's also the case for the working cluster.
We tried bouncing the instance but pg_wal was not cleaned up afterwards.
In the past the only solution was to reinit the cluster member - but that should be just an emergency workaround.
Maybe someone has experienced a similar problem and can help.

"There's an inactive replication slot in the standby instance, but that's also the case for the working cluster." That still is the likely cause of the problem. Get rid of it. Stale replication slots are always detrimental unless that hold no restart_lsn or catalog_xmin.

Maybe the inactive slot is reserving wal on one instance, but is not on the other (because it was never initialized).  Anyway, what is the point of keeping it?

The replication slot is recreated in the standby instance after a few seconds. I already tried restarting the instance. No change - the replications slot is recreated after dropping it and so the directory pg_wal keeps growing.
